# Ignore changes to files that are already in repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, hgignore

Adding files to `.hgignore` will prevent them from being tracked. But we have some files that we want to be in the repository - we just don't want users to ever commit changes. Is there a way to ignore changes to these files, so they won't get committed in an `hg commit`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial: How to ignore changes to a tracked file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856571/mercurial-how-to-ignore-changes-to-a-tracked-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cannot be done in Mercurial — a file is either tracked or untracked (and then optionally ignored). You should instead version a template file and then ignore the real file.

So add `config.template` to version control and add `config` to `.hgignore`. Ask your developers to copy the template to the real name and customize it as needed.