# Mercurial: Tracking configuration files, but in a different branch

Tags: git, mercurial, branch, branching-and-merging

In my current project I have followed the [usual advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2857512/699305) for configuration files: **Commit configuration files as templates, then copy them to another location** so that configuration settings don't end up in the change history.

However, it is nice to be able to track the history of configuration files as well -- for all the same reasons that version control is useful in a single-user setting. What is the best way to set this up, **on a clone that I use for development?**

#### Background:

For deployed clones, I have been doing this by switching a new branch, say `localconfig`, adding the configuration files to it, and merging updates from `default` as they come in. This works fine.

But when doing development, it is a pain to worki in the `localconfig` branch: each commit has to be somehow rebased to `default` (or whatever branch I'm developing in), then merged back into `localconfig`. So I have kept the configuration files uncommitted on my development clone.

What's the best way to have it both ways? Basically, I need to either work in `localconfig` but easily commit to `default`, or work in `default` but have the configuration files present (so that the software can run).

I'm leaning toward the second option, perhaps something like this:

1. commit the configuration to `localconfig`
2. switch to back to `default`
3. Extract untracked copies of the committed files, e.g. with `hg revert -r localconfig`.

But when I make changes to the configuration files, I'll have to switch to the `localconfig` branch and commit them. That's just begging for problems with merging conflicts, untracked files blocking the switch to `localconfig`, etc. Does anyone have experience with this or a good solution?

I use mercurial, but I expect the question applies with any modern DVCS.