# Ignore on commit in TortoiseHg

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

Is there similar to SVN's [ignore on commit](http://blog.baljeetsingh.net/2009/02/tips-tricks-svn-ignore-on-commit.html) feature in TortoiseHg?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884545/is-there-an-ignore-on-commit-option-in-mercurial), but need a way to do it via UI for non development team members.

Comment: You mean TortoiseSVN's ignore-on-commit

Comment: I understand what this feature does now. But I'm not sure I understand what the purpose in doing so is. The point of a version control system (particularly a distributed one) is to be able to undo changes and walk the list of changes to various files. Changing a file and not checking it in seems to go against that concept. Perhaps this is a workflow issue, and Hg's branching would be a better way to do what you're wanting to do.

Comment: @NicolBolas - There are many files like that, like project files that may change all the time, but should not be committed, but a committed version should exist to open the project etc.

Comment: @manojlds: Project files define what source code gets built into what object files and executables. Thus, if you add a file to the project, then you have changed the project, and if that file is versioned, you need to commit that change along with other changes. What IDE are you using that is changing your project files "all the time"? Even Visual Studio doesn't change .sln and .vcproj files unless you actually make a change that affects the build of the project in question. The .ncb and .suo files change, but those should not be under version control to begin with.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Xcode does. And also look at the second link in the question. And I am just giving examples. And take the context of the question - it is for something in GUI for non developers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to ignore files in kiln/mercurial using tortoise hg "that are part of the repository"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351076/how-to-ignore-files-in-kiln-mercurial-using-tortoise-hg-that-are-part-of-the-re). Please see [my answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351076/how-to-ignore-files-in-kiln-mercurial-using-tortoise-hg-that-are-part-of-the-re/7354899#7354899).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can unmark files, prepared for commit in GUI
2. You can in THG settings (global or per-project) define auto-exclude list
3. **Changelists** per-se doesn't exist in  mercurial as useless thing (it's bad even in SVN)